# iOS app - data not displayed in Today Widget and Notification extensions only on iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios13

I have an iOS app that has a Today Widget and a Notification extensions
The app was built using iOS12 SDK and when running the app on an iPhone with iOS12, both extensions work fine.
When downloading the app from the Store to an iPhone that is running iOS13, both extensions do not show any data (Widget shows "Unable to Load").

When using Xcode 11 and iOS13 SDK, building the app on an iPhone with iOS13, still both extensions do not show any data.
I have tried to add a new Today Widget without adding any code to the swift file or the Storyboard that were created and still see "Unable to Load".

Creating A new app with only a Today Widget, work fine

Does anyone have this issue?
Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

[image: Today Widget]

[image: Notification extension]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have a plain file in the project that was named "Versions". Once I removed the file, both extensions work perfectly fine.